# Bad request (400) with OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I am using `Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth`. I was able to register `Google`, `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Stack Exchange`, `MyOpenID`...

Now I am trying to add `Microsoft Live`, so I registered:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient("applicationID", "key");
```

and called

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication("microsoft", Url.Action("Authorization", new { returnUrl = "/" }));
```

To this point everything is working fine, I get redirected to the login page. The problem is when I come back to

```
OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();
```

It says:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

What do I have to do?

Comment: I am having the same, problem, for me it is not working for Facebook and Google either. I get same 400 error. how about yours? were you able to implement oAuth for Facebook and google?

Comment: I'm getting a 401 (unauthorise) error when trying to logon through twitter as soon as I click the button.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  After a lot of research, I came across [this bit of source code](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/OpenAuthSecurityManager.cs#L205) with the comment:

```
// Only OAuth2 requires the return url value for the verify authenticaiton step
```

This means that when you call `VerifyAuthentication`, you must use the overload that passes the return url for validation by the oauth2 provider (the Microsoft Live ID provider in this case).

Sure enough, when I dig through [the walkthrough on the asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc), I find that they are indeed passing back the return url, as the url from the action of the callback.

So instead of:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();
```

You need:

```
var returnUrl = Url.Action("Authorization", new { returnUrl = "/" })
OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(returnUrl);
```

The return url should match exactly the same as you specified earlier in the `RequestAuthentication` method.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Redirect Domain that you are using?  I found (when doing this) that, since I had specified my actual domain name, I needed to have the domain name point to the local site.

To work around, I added an entry to the hosts file to point my domain at 127.0.0.1 (i.e. because I was debugging and running locally).

Comment: I was getting an error related to this, so I had to specify an unique domain name and point it to 127.0.0.1 on `hosts` file. After that it took some time and that error stopped. Does this code work for you? If it does, then it is probably some bug related to my app... I will try to create a new one...

Comment: I created a fresh new app to a unique domain (127.0.0.1 on hosts file), it asks my permission, I accept, it goes back to my app on `OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication()` and breaks with `(400) Bad Request`